# Objective C - Detect if finger is held on screen at app startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'd like to perform an action when the user has their finger held on the screen when my app startups.

To give an example: When the App launches and the launch screen is showing up, the user has a finger on the screen as long as the first ViewController appears. When the first ViewController gets into the viewDidAppear() function, I want to detect, that the users finger is on the screen and perform an action, like f.ex. jumping straight into the lastest received email. Basically this is supposed to be a kind of shortcut to an main action.

Is there any method to detect an already laying finger on the screen? To be exactly I'd like to check for the tap in viewDidAppear()

Comment: you want to detect finger before app starts, or during app starts? can you explain whole scenario?

Comment: To give an example: When the App launches and the launch screen is showing up, the user has a finger on the screen as long as the first ViewController appears. When the first ViewController gets into the viewDidAppear() function, I want to detect, that the users finger is on the screen and perform an action, like f.ex. jumping straight into the lastest received email. Basically this is supposed to be a kind of shortcut to an main action.

Comment: But isn't this exactly why iOS 9 gave you actual Shortcuts (force-touch on icon in home screen)?

Comment: Yes but not every customer has an iPhone 6S so I'd like to add this option too.

Comment: I think it is not possible. If we apply UIResponder methods like touchbegin or move etc, they won't detect

Comment: One more thing, why don't you show alert with okay to go to mail else normal

Comment: Yes an UIAlertView would be another good option, if the detection didn't work. But I couldn't find any solution too, so maybe it's not possible, like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the nature of Time has changed since the last time I checked, your app cannot detect what the user *was* doing *before* the app launched. The app, *ex hypothesi*, was not running at that time. And the mere presence of a finger on the screen during app launch will not generate a touch event that the app can detect.

The *system* can detect it, however, since *is* running before your app launches. That is why Apple added force-touch Shortcuts (for appropriate hardware). The only way you can do what you're asking is to rely on that API. Hardware that lacks this feature will simply have to do without this feature.

(After all, this is how Apple makes money: by trying to make users jealous of hardware they don't have, so that they buy new hardware. You would want to rob Apple of its income by reading this feature backwards onto old hardware, even if you could, now would you?)